# How can I ensure that the callback for setInterval is called exactly at the interval specified?

Tags: javascript

Take this function for example:

```
function mySlowFunction(baseNumber) {
    console.time('mySlowFunction');
    var result = 0; 
    for (var i = Math.pow(baseNumber, 10); i >= 0; i--) {       
        result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i);
    };
    console.timeEnd('mySlowFunction');
    return result;
}
```

This is a very CPU-intensive function. It takes around 3 seconds to complete for `mySlowFunction(5)`.

Now consider this code:

```
setInterval(() => console.log("interval"), 1000); 
mySlowFunction(5);
```

I expect it to log "interval" every second, but I understand that since `mySlowFunction` is running on the thread and JS is single-threaded, the callback for `setInterval` is executed only after `mySlowFunction` completes.

Is there any way I can ensure the callback is called on the specified interval? I want this in a browser-based environment.

Comment: You simply shouldn't be blocking the main thread with anything for several seconds. If you have some intensive calculations to do, put them in a web worker or break them up into interruptible chunks with `setTimeout`.

Comment: I don't believe you can be sure of that, precisely for the reason you stated : JS is single-threaded. I don't think there's a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't expect the interval to fire at the specified delay.
[Here -> ( *Reasons for delays longer than specified* )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)  are a couple of reasons why the delay may take longer than expected. Anyway, if you still want to ensure that your interval will fire before your `mySlowFunction` finished execution you can as mentioned in the comments use a [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Worker)

> *The Worker interface of the Web Workers API represents a background task that can be easily created and can send messages back to its creator.*

to allocate the computation of `mySlowFunction` to a different thread.

Here is an example:

```js
var blobWorker = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob([ '(',
    function() {
        self.onmessage = function(e) {
          
         var result = 0; 
         for (var i = Math.pow(e.data, 10); i >= 0; i--) {
            result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i);
         };
         
          self.postMessage(result);
        };
    }.toString(),
')()' ], { type: 'application/javascript' } ) );

var worker = new Worker( blobWorker );

worker.onmessage = function(e) {

    console.log("result from mySlowWorker:", e.data);
}

var intervalId = setInterval(() => console.log("interval"), 1000);

worker.postMessage(5);

URL.revokeObjectURL( blobWorker );

setTimeout( _ => { clearInterval(intervalId); console.log('done') }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer delay is not guaranteed in Javascript. Asynchronous events such as timers and mouse clicks are executed one at a time, due to Javascript's single threaded nature.